# GetChanges() of datatable in c#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have  dataTables  DTsource,DTtarget and DTdiff

```
DTsource.Merge(DTtarget);
DTsource.AcceptChanges();
DTdiff=DTsource.GetChanges();
```

there are different sets of records in source and target. **but DTdiff is always null**.
any pointers please....

Comment: [_"GetChanges() Gets a copy of the DataSet containing all changes made to it since it was last loaded, or **since AcceptChanges was called**"_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.getchanges.aspx). What do you expect?

Comment: @CodeCaster  Am trying to get the difference between source and target. Ny this code I expect DTdiff would be populated with records that are present only in target.

Comment: @Flins: Than you should avoid the `AcceptChanges()` call **before** calling `GetChanges()`.

Comment: tried that also.. no luck

Answer (score 1):

It seems obvious that you should do it like that:

```
DTsource.AcceptChanges();
DTsource.Merge(DTtarget);
DTdiff=DTsource.GetChanges();
```

All previous changes are accepted before the merge. After the merge, GetChanges contains only differences of target.